# Google Maps API InfoWindows Inside Class

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to have several markers on on a map, each with some customized information in an InfoWindow that pops up on clicking the marker.  I figured it would be cleaner to put all of this inside an object so that I could abstract away the messiness, however I am having some issues.  I load the Google maps API as:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(home_params['lat'], home_params['lon']),
      zoom: 13
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
       $('#overview').animate({height: "100%", opacity: "0.9"}, 1000);
       home = new location(home_params, map);  //instantiate a new location object
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', mapclick);
}

var home_params = {{ home }};  //Filled in by Jinja2
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And the location object is defined as:

```
function location(info, map) {
    // Extract variables from array
    this.id = info['id'];
    this.loc = new google.maps.LatLng(info['lat'], info['lon']);
    this.name = info['name'];
    this.addr = info['address'];
    this.city = info['city'];
    this.note = info['comments'];

    this.map = map;

    // Popup window definition
    s = "<div id='loc_popup_" + this.id + "'><h1>" + this.name + "</h1><h2>" + this.addr + ", " + this.city + "</h2></div>";

    this.popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: s
    });

    this.open = function() {
        this.popup.open(this.map, this.loc);
    };

    this.close = function() {
        this.popup.close();
    };

    // Marker definition
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.loc,
        map: this.map,
        title: this.name
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', $.proxy(this.open, this));
}
```

However clicking the marker (or even just calling the .open() method directly) causes the following error in the console:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a.get("map")')
```

Obviously no popup is displayed, but I have no idea what is causing this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing.  Immediately after posting this I looked at the code more closely and realized I was calling the `InfoWindow.open()` method with a `google.maps.LatLng` object instead of a `google.maps.Marker` object.  Changing this solved the problem.